# Commutator terms in the $\mathcal{N} = 2$ Super Yang-Mills Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, seiberg-witten-theory

I'm reading Seiberg-Witten Theory with $\mathcal{N} = 2$ supersymmetry from these notes https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9701069. In the second term of the Lagrangian (72), we have a term from the chiral superfields.

$$\mathcal{L} = Tr \int d^2\theta d^2\bar{\theta} \Phi^\dagger e^{-2V} \Phi.$$

Given

$$ V = V^a T^a $$
$$ \Phi = \Phi^a T^a $$

With $T^a$ as the generators in the adjoint representation,
$V$ is a vector multiplet $V = V(A_\mu,\lambda,D)$ and
$\Phi$ is a chiral multiplet $\Phi = \Phi(A,\psi,F)$.

If we expand $V$ and $\Phi$ with the fields above in the Lagrangian, we expect it to have commutator terms such as $D[A^\dagger,A]$. Now, how is this possible?

If we take, for simplicity, $$V = \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 \bar{\theta}^2 D^a T^a$$ and $$ \Phi = (A^a + i\theta \sigma^\mu \bar{\theta} \partial_\mu A^a - \frac{1}{4}\theta^2\bar{\theta}^2 \Box A^a) T^a$$ or, in other words, $A_\mu = \psi = \lambda = F = 0$,

Then we should have
$$\mathcal{L} = Tr \int d^2\theta d^2\bar{\theta} (\Phi^\dagger \Phi - 2  \Phi^\dagger V\Phi).$$
Focusing on the second term, we have
$$\mathcal{L}^{(2)} = -Tr A^\dagger D A.$$
But, we are expected to find
$$\mathcal{L}^{(2)} = Tr D[A^\dagger,A].$$
Where did I do wrong? How can I get the term $Tr D A^\dagger A$?

Note: I believe that $Tr\Phi^\dagger e^{-2V} \Phi$ is real since $$(\Phi^\dagger e^{-2V} \Phi)^\dagger = \Phi^\dagger e^{-2V^\dagger} \Phi = \Phi^\dagger e^{-2V} \Phi.$$